# Python to sort tag with different attributes

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, attributes, tags

I have a list from `links = set(soup.findAll('a'))`, now I want to sort them, but `links = sorted(links)` got error, what can I sort it?

The original list and any else attributes:

```
<a href="//weathernews.jp/typhoon/">台風</a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/190035/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/130155/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a href="//weathernews.jp/warning/">警報・注意報</a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/140125/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/170145/?fm=tp_index"></a>
```

I want to sort it to

```
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/190035/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/170145/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/140125/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a class="list" href="https://weathernews.jp/s/topics/201809/130155/?fm=tp_index"></a>
<a href="//weathernews.jp/typhoon/">台風</a>
<a href="//weathernews.jp/warning/">警報・注意報</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to first map the links to strings and then sort it.

```
links = soup.findAll('a')
links = map(str, links)
links = sorted(links)
```

OR

Simply,

```
links = sorted(map(str, links))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this

```
links = sorted(links, key=lambda x: str(x), reverse=False)
```

Comment: `reverse=False` is the default value. and the lambda function can be replaced by the function object directly. So, it would be `sorted(links, key=str)`